# Job not running on start_date SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

Has anyone had any issues with the start_date in SQL developer when the job won't execute on the `start_date` provided in the schedule, but it runs fine against the repeat interval?

My understanding was that the `start_date` would be the first execution and then subsequent executions use the repeat interval.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
        repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=DAILY',    
        start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-07-23 10:00:00.000000000 +01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR'),
        comments => 'Created by DBA',
        schedule_name  => '"TEST"');
END;
```

Comment: It would help if you posted code you used to create that job.

Comment: Do not add code in comments. **[edit]** your question instead

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a *schedule*. What does it execute (if anything). Here's an example I used recently and it works as expected. See it if helps.

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
      job_name          => 'p_mailovi',
      job_type          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      job_action        => 'BEGIN pkg_mail.p_mailovi; end;',
      start_date        => TO_DATE ('15.05.2018 10:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
      repeat_interval   => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; BYHOUR=9,14; BYMINUTE=0',
      enabled           => TRUE,
      comments          => 'Mailovi');
END;
/
```